# Show that the following inequality holds.

Tags: inequality

Suppose that n and p are positive integers. Show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^p < \frac{(n)^{p+1}}{p+1} < \sum_{k=1}^n k^p.$$

Comment: The middle expression is $\int_0^nx^p\;dx$. How do the outer sums relate to the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1^p\leq\displaystyle \int_{1}^2 x^p dx,2^p \leq \displaystyle \int_{2}^3 x^p dx,...., (n-1)^p \leq \displaystyle \int_{n-1}^n x^p dx\Rightarrow \text{LHS} \leq \displaystyle \int_{1}^n x^p dx < \displaystyle \int_{0}^n x^p dx = \dfrac{n^p}{p+1}$.

And $1^p > \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 x^p dx, 2^p \geq \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 x^p dx, ...., n^p \geq \displaystyle \int_{n-1}^n x^p dx\Rightarrow \text{RHS} > \displaystyle \int_{0}^n x^p dx= \dfrac{n^p}{p+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "Riemann Sum, or Riemann Integral". If $n \rightarrow \infty$, then your left part is equal to you center part.